# Java MySql Communication link Failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, netbeans-8

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I Surrender I already tried the best that I can Please help me I just need to make a connection to my database

I am using hostinger.ph as the hosting site of my database

**DBconnect.java**

```
package mftis;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBconnect {
private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public DBconnect(){
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Success in using the Driver");

    con =            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.hostinger.ph/u366906409_mftis","u366906409_mftis","mftis2016");
    st = con.createStatement();

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
}

}
```

**login_window**

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DBconnect connect = new DBconnect();
}
```

Please I will really appreciate the help
anyway my Database is over the internet all the tutorials i can found is using localhost

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: nope, i already tried that one and it doesnt work, they are using localhost like xampp etc. im over the internet

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Class.forName(driverClass).newInstance();
        Properties connProp = new Properties();
        connProp.setProperty("user", properties.getDbUser());
        connProp.setProperty("password", properties.getDbPasswd());
        connProp.setProperty("connectTimeout", timeout);
        connProp.setProperty("socketTimeout", timeout);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,  connProp);
```

Where dburl is :

```
String url = "" + properties.getDbServer() + ":" + properties.getDbPort() + "/" + properties.getDbName();

            url = "jdbc:mysql://" + url + "?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";

        return url;
```

Comment: may i know where did you get the driverClass?

Comment: I've used Driver.class.getName() where Driver is imported from
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver